# Preposition ( made of vs made from )

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

Fill in the right word.
Bread is usually made ______ wheat.
1) of
2) from
3) with
4) by

Answer (score 0):

2) from

would be the correct answer

Explain:

"**Make of**" means that the material is just changed its form

For example: This shirt is made of cotton. This house is made of bricks.

"**Make of**" means that the material has gone through a process of changing.

In this case, the material 'wheat' has gone through the process of baking -> turn into bread.

Answer (score 0):

The correct preposition in the sentence is "from", not "of".

When you make bread, the material wheat changes its form completely in such a way that it's no more wheat or, in other words, you cannot see it. In this case you use the "from".

On the other hand, if the material used  in making an object doesn't change its form completely or you  can still recognize the  material, you use the preposition "of". For example:

This table is made of wood.

Answer (score 0):

-1 for not doing a research and not looking into official sources which can be found when googling.

[**Cambridge Grammar:**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/word-order-and-focus/made-from-made-of-made-out-of-made-with)

- **Made from** - We often use made from when we talk about how something is manufactured
- **Made of** - We use made of when we talk about the basic material or qualities of something. It has a meaning similar to ‘**composed of**’
- **Made out of** - We usually use made out of when we talk about something that has been changed or transformed from one thing into another
- **Made with** - We use made with most often to talk about the ingredients of food and drink